# Is it possible to change the logging level while application is running?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

This may be a stupid question, but since it came to my mind, I am asking to see if this makes any sense.

- I have a project that runs on customer's machine.
- It is started via command-line and creates log inside a `logs` folder. The logging levels are set inside `log4j.xml`. The current statements I see are `INFO`, `DEBUG` and `ERROR`.

**Requirement**
- I am working on a feature where I am introducing `TRACE` option.
- I do **not** want to log these statements by default (just log at the level of `DEBUG`).
- But in case of any issues, I want to enable the `TRACE` level (via some environment variable, system property) that my running application can pick and start logging the `TRACE` statements as well

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at a previous [question](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/LoggerConfig.html) already answered.

Comment: *"via some environment variable"*? You can't change environment variable *while application is running*, so that won't work. And although you can change a system property while application is running, it's be better to just update the logging configuration directly.

Comment: If your configuration is defined in `log4j.xml`, why did you tag `logback` and `slf4j`? They have nothing to do with Log4j configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web project, a very convenient way is to place this JSP in your WebContent folder.

It will print all the available loggers and you can change the log level simply by clicking.

https://gist.github.com/iamkristian/943918